# Overriding assignment operator in derived class

Tags: c++, overloading

Assume class D is derived from a base class B where D doesn't have any data members
I came up with the following to overload the assignment operator = for class D

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class B {
    private:
      std::string* str = nullptr;

public:
  const B& operator=(const B& rhs) { 
   return *this;
  }
 
};

class D : public B {
public:
D& operator=(const D& empl) {
               if ( this != &empl ) {
                   (B&)(*this) = empl;
                  
               }
               return *this;
          }
};

int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

since there is no data member in it. I could simply use the Base class assignment operator. 
Is this a correct implementation?

Comment: "_since there is no data member in it. I could simply use the Base class assignment operator.Is this a correct implementation?_" - Of what?

Comment: Implement the assignment operator in the Derived class

Comment: Why are you needing the `D::operator=` for to begin with? What is the actual problem it's supposed to solve?

Comment: And please note that using a C-style cast is usually a red flag that you're doing something wrong. Another red flag is that `B::str` is a pointer. Why is it a pointer?

Comment: The assignment operator for `B` fails to assign anything from `rhs` -- it forgets to assign `str`.  Instead it just returns.  Code like this is a huge source of very hard-to-find bugs.  The assignment operator's job should be one thing and one thing only -- to assign to an existing object the contents (in whatever way) the source object.  You failed to do that in `B`.  It's working should be seamless -- no side effects, nothing missing, etc.  The destination object should be a "clone" of the source object.

Comment: Also, `operator=` is a non-const operator, so why is it returning a reference to a `const` object? It should be returning a reference to a non-const object.

Comment: The use of C-style casts always makes me think that the author does not know which type of cast is really happening or does not care. Both alternatives are concerning to me. I recommend making a habit of not doing those, even if this means the code gets longer: `static_cast<B&>(*this) = ...;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a better implementation would be:

```
if (this != &empl)
    B::operator= (empl);
```

This avoids the cast, which is, at best, dubious.

But, as @Some programmer dude says, what is the purpose of `D::operator=` anyway?  It doesn't do anything that `B::operator=` doesn't do, so you don't need it.